# sqlite3 change in the func callback the parameter void* notUsed to map<string, string> C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I need to return a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` from callback(sqlite3), but I not succeeded. I tried - but nothing. I will be very glad if you will help me.

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    sqlite3* db;
    char* zErrMsg;
    sqlite3_open("someDB.db", &db);

    //do something...

    string query = "select * from myTable";
    map<string, string> myMap;
    sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), callback, &myMap, &zErrMsg);

    //do something...

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}



int callback(void* notUsed, int argc, char** argv, char** azCol)
{
    /*
    change void* notUsed to map<string, string>
    ???how???
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Within `callback`, do `auto& myMap = *static_cast<map<string, string>*>(notUsed);`. Then use `myMap` as you normally would.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: To repeat myself: you really should use a [cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5456/sqlite3-stmt-prepared-statement-c-api/19406/reading-data-from-a-cursor).